# Intel Graphics Drivers Update

Tags: intel-graphics

How would I update my intel graphics drivers I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 currently upgrading to 16.04 at the moment. Even if they are up to date on Linux I think it'd be kinda handy if I need to update the drivers. Thank you for helping this semi Linux newbie(I'm starting to get comfortable with Linux but still have some basic things I don't know)

Answer (score 1):

[01.org](https://01.org/about) is Intel's open source community where open source work that Intel engineers are involved in is pulled together. The [Intel Graphics for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) driver website does not have any Intel graphics drivers for later than Ubuntu 17.04, so I assume that the Intel graphics driver is built-in in 18.04 and updated with the Software Updater application. For **Ubuntu 16.04** visit this link: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/.

This is optional because if Intel graphics works OK with the built-in driver in 16.04, then you don't need to manually download anything. However if you are experiencing screen tearing when using a second monitor, the Intel graphics driver from https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/ may be able to fix it.